# Is it safe NOT to use prepared-statement after I have used it once?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am making a login system which needs to check the validity of a user. Basically, it takes three steps.

1. Get `$username` from user input
2. Check whether `$username` exists in the database

   ```
   SELECT * FROM members WHERE name = $username LIMIT 1
   ```
3. Update login information for `$username` (e.g. login time, IP, ...)

   ```
   UPDATE members SET ip = $ip WHERE name = $username
   ```

In the second step, assume I have used prepared-statement to query the (MySQL) database, in order to avoid SQL injection. I wonder there is still a need to use prepared-statement in the third step.

My logic is that `$username` has passed the second step, so it should be a valid argument. To save extra server round trip due to the use of prepared-statement, it seems that there is no need to update the database using prepared-statement in the third step.

I am very new to using database. Hope someone could clarify my problem. :)

Comment: can the username have values like ' , " ?

Comment: Assume that username can contain any character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the username has a special character in it, it will affect your second query. This is referred to as a [second order SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_Order_SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 3):

no! always use prepared statements. you can pass 10 validations but delete your database in the 11th

Comment: It doesn't exactly work that way. You don't **always** need to use prepared statements, and prepared statements are not a silver bullets. They are a tool you need to know how to use properly. That's all.

Comment: when you are getting a parameter from outside of your  code, you should always use prepared statements

Comment: That's true. Actually, whenever you are getting a parameter, even from inside your code, you should be using prepared statements. But not all queries are suitable for prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

If $username is something evil in the first line, it will be in the second line.

Unless you overwrite it with a value read from the database.

Comment: I am confusing about how an evil $username can return me something for the "SELECT" statement?

Comment: It can do with your data what you can do, maybe drop some tables. The keyword to search for is **SQL injection**.